IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7
I am trying to assess whether the lips of a person are moving too much while the mouth is closed (to conclude it is chewing).
The mouth closed part is done without any issue, but when I try to assess the lip movement through landmarks (dlib) there seems to be a problem with the last landmark of the mouth.
Inspired by the mouth example (https://github.com/mauckc/mouth-open/blob/master/detect_open_mouth.py#L17), I wrote the following function:
def lips_aspect_ratio(shape):
    # grab the indexes of the facial landmarks for the lip
    (mStart, mEnd) = (61, 68)
    lip = shape[mStart:mEnd]
    print(len(lip))
    # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of
    # vertical lip landmarks (x, y)-coordinates
    # to reach landmark 68 I need to get lib[7] not lip[6] (while I get lip[7] I get IndexOutOfBoundError)
    A = dist.euclidean(lip[1], lip[6])  # 62, 68
    B = dist.euclidean(lip[3], lip[5])  # 64, 66

    # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal
    # lip landmark (x, y)-coordinates
    C = dist.euclidean(lip[0], lip[4])  # 61, 65

    # compute the lip aspect ratio
    mar = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

    # return the lip aspect ratio
    return mar

The landmark of the lips are (61, 68), when I extract the lip as lip = shape[61:68] and try to access the last landmark as lip[7] I get the following error:
IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7

Why is that? and How to get the last landmark of the lip/face

Otherwise How to define an aspect ratio for the lips to conclude they are moving significantly? That should really be another question. Edit this one to remove this "2nd question sneaked in", and pose it as a separate one. After all, you haven't had the chance to play with the fixed code yet. You have the data to best answer whether your detection algorithm works. Play with it first. Visualize it - don't just look at numbers. Look at plots, in real time.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79059576/top-lip-to-nose-ratio-aspect-to-detect-chewing-activity-not-working-as-expected

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79059053/lip-movement-as-a-chewing-sign-in-computer-vision-tasks

lip = shape[61:68]

The slices exclude the end element. So you got 7 elements: 61,62,63,64, 65,66,67. And len(lip) == 7 confirms that.
If there truly are 8 points for the lip shape, and they include element 68, the slice should be:
lip = shape[61:69]
assert(len(range(61, 69) == 8)
assert(len(lip) == 8)

Note that if shape is sufficiently long, then len(shape[a:b:c]) == len(range(a, b, c)). That's because the range function acts like taking a slice out of an infinitely long list of integers (with caveats).
So, the problem is a classic off-by-one, not much to do with AI/image analysis :)

Is the mentioned function able to tell whether the lips are significantly moving while the mouth is closed? if not how to define the lip aspect ratio to tell the lips are significantly moving around (given the mouth is closed)? I mean is there a better formula than mar = (A + B) / (2.0 * C) in this case?

@Sam if you have another question, ask another question. Your question is already answered. So you need to ask another one :)
