top lip to nose ratio aspect to detect chewing activity not working as expected
I want to know whether a person is chewing in front of a camera or not using dlib's facemarks.
For this end I compute the distance from nose to top lip and derive the mean, then if the that value is bigger than a threshold then we could say that the person is chewing.
To compute the nose to top lip distance I do the following:
def lip_nose_distance(shape):
    top_lip = shape[50:54]
     

    nose = shape[32:36]
    nose = np.mean(nose, axis=0)
    top_lip = np.mean(top_lip, axis=0)

    distance = abs(nose[0] - top_lip[0])
    return distance

Then iterating of the buffered frame from the video like so:
old_lip_mar1 = 0.0
for (i, landmark) in enumerate(landmark_buffer):
   
    lip_dist = lip_nose_distance(shape)
    if old_lip_mar1>0.0: 
        print("old_lip_mar1 ", old_lip_mar1)
        print("lip_dist ", lip_dist)
        if abs(lip_dist-old_lip_mar1) > 0.015:
            print("lip is moving around too much! so the user is chewing")
        else:
            print("lip is not moving around too much!")
        
  
    old_lip_mar1 = lip_dist

The buffers are obtained using:
video_list = os.listdir(VIDEO_PATH)  # Read video list

# for vid_name in video_list:  # Iterate on video files
vid_path = VIDEO_PATH + "chewing_2.avi"
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)  # Read video

# Parse into frames
frame_buffer = []  # A list to hold frame images
frame_buffer_color = []  # A list to hold original frame images
while (True):
    success, frame = vid.read()  # Read frame
    if not success:
        break  # Break if no frame to read left
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert image into grayscale
    frame_buffer.append(gray)  # Add image to the frame buffer
    
vid.release()


landmark_buffer = []  # A list to hold face landmark information
for (i, image) in enumerate(frame_buffer):  # Iterate on frame buffer
 
    
    result = get_rotated_mouth_loc_with_height(image)
    landmark = predictor(image, result['rect'])  # Detect face landmarks
    landmark = shape_to_list(landmark)
    landmark_buffer.append(landmark)
    shape = result['shape']

The code to work required the following constants and imports:
import dlib
import cv2
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS = OrderedDict([
    ("mouth", (48, 68)),
    ("inner_mouth", (60, 68)),
    ("right_eyebrow", (17, 22)),
    ("left_eyebrow", (22, 27)),
    ("right_eye", (36, 42)),
    ("left_eye", (42, 48)),
    ("nose", (27, 36)),
    ("jaw", (0, 17))
])

Finally an example on which the code could run is found in:
https://streamable.com/lrlchs

For now the error I am getting is that the results are not the ones that are expected (e.g., I get
lip is not moving around too much! while they are!) plus the values of the distances don't change accross frames (e.g., ('old_lip_mar1 ', 0.75),('lip_dist ', 0.75) )

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79059053/lip-movement-as-a-chewing-sign-in-computer-vision-tasks

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79057529/lip-aspect-ratio-calculation-issue
